# plantuml command over multiple lines

Tags: clang, doxygen, plantuml

When using plantuml in c style code comments /// then clang adds a \ line break into the comment.

```
    /// @startuml
    ///  m_alengthyline.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx .[#green].> \
    ///  another.lengthyline.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : reads
    /// @enduml
```

Then I get a compiler warning
multi-line comment [-Wcomment]

I do want to keep the line length constraint and I do want to keep the doxygen comment style.
Is there any way to tell plantuml that the command goes over 2 lines or any other trick?

thank you

tried to find a propper command in the plantuml documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility I see is to reorganize your graph a bit like

```
@startuml
 package m_alengthyline {
   class "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" as X
 }
 package another
 {
   package lengthyline
   {
     class "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" as Y
   }
 }
 X.[#green].>  Y: reads
@enduml
```

**Edit**
Based on the comment (see below): "this will change the character of the diagram and add new boxes If there is no solution, then i mix with multiline comments for lengthy lines /** * ... */ –
Mat"

I created for the original version, assuming this is:

```
@startuml
m_alengthyline.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx .[#green].> another.lengthyline.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : reads
@enduml
```

and for the new version the diagram an in bot cases I get:
[image]

So the comment is unclear to me.

Comment: this will change the character of the diagram and add new boxes
If there is no solution, then i mix with multiline comments for lengthy lines
/** 
* ...
 */

Comment: @mat what do yo mean by "this will change the character of the diagram" and "", can you give an example? I get in the old and the new situation the same image (see my edit in my answer)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is similar and your solution with as renaming solved my problem. Thank you